# How to use fmt.scanln read from a string separated by spaces

Tags: string, input, go

Want "30 of month" but get "30"

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var s string
    fmt.Scanln(&s)
    fmt.Println(s)
    return
}

$ go run test.go
31 of month
31
```

> Scanln is similar to Scan, but stops scanning at a newline and after the final item there must be a newline or EOF.

Answer (score 11):

The fmt Scan family scan space-separated tokens.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var s1 string
    var s2 string
    fmt.Scanln(&s1,&s2)
    fmt.Println(s1)
    fmt.Println(s2)
    return
}
```

You can try bufio scan

```
package main
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        s := scanner.Text()
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: thx...but if I put `fmt.Println(s)` outside of the loop, no values will be output. how can i stop the loop

Comment: func main() {
 scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
 if ok := scanner.Scan();ok {
  fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
 }
}      scanner.Scan() will return bool when end scan

Comment: Second snippet worked great. Why are you checking for error after for loop ? would the if else block be executed here in case of an error ? Because there is a infinite for loop before it.

Comment: @trquoccuong - I have the same query as Ishan above, doesn't checking for the error after fmt.Println(s), break things? you are checking scanner.Err() after printing the scan?

Comment: bufio solution is great!

Comment: I have to use an if statement instead of for loop, so that the program will proceed after the first input. If I use a for loop, the program will keep asking me for input forever. How would I get out of the loop if I used a for loop?

Comment: I agree with @Zass

Answer (score 9):

If you really want to include the spaces, you may consider using `fmt.Scanf()` with format `%q  a double-quoted string safely escaped with Go syntax` , for example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var s string
    fmt.Scanf("%q", &s)
    fmt.Println(s)
    return
}
```

Run it and:

```
$ go run test.go
"31 of month"
31 of month
```

Comment: With this approach i'm getting: expected quoted string trying to input "hello world" string

Comment: Not a very good approach, as it forces the user to use double quotes around their input in the console

Answer (score 5):

Here is the working program

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var strInput string
    fmt.Println("Enter a string ")
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    if scanner.Scan() {
        strInput = scanner.Text()
    }
    
    fmt.Println(strInput)
}
```

which reads strings like " d skd a efju N"
and prints the same string as output.

Comment: question specifically asked about `fmt.scanln`, not how to achieve same result with different method

Comment: I voted up as this question is accessable from search engine and it indeed works

Comment: gondo the answer is "you can't do this with scanln"