# strings.Split, stdin not returning slice/array

Tags: go

It seems that strings.split(" ") is not returning an array. I have no idea why this is. I'm sure I am using it in a similar context elsewhere.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var seedCost float64
    var lawnNo int
    var in string
    var area float64
    var wh []string

    fmt.Scanln(&seedCost) //2 is inputted
    fmt.Scanln(&lawnNo)   //3
    lawnCost := 0.00

    for i := 0; i < lawnNo; i++ {
        fmt.Scanln(&in) //2 3 is inputted
        wh = strings.Split(in, " ")
        fmt.Println(wh[0])
        fmt.Println(wh[1]) //Test throwing exception, index out of range
        w, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(wh[0], 64)
        h, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(wh[1], 64) //EXCEPTIONAL LINE, index out of range

        area = w * h
        lawnCost += area * seedCost
    }

    ans := strconv.FormatFloat(lawnCost, 'E', 8, 64)
    fmt.Println(ans)
}
```

Comment: `strings.Split` is returning a slice of just one element if you're getting an index out of range error.

Comment: But with the input of 2[space]3 why would strings.Split() only return a slice of 1?

Comment: Are you sure that's what the input is?

Comment: Er I typed it myself so yes.

Is it possible that Scanln includes some \n char or something. This still shouldn't cause any issues?

Comment: :D - I'll try it locally myself, but you could inspect the string before you split it to validate your assumptions

Comment: I just tried it locally and it seems to work fine for me... What operating system are you on?

Comment: Windows :( 

I narrowed it down though. The string is in fact 2 when 2 3 is inputted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**fmt.Scanln stops reading after the spaces.**

Two Approaches to solve this Problem

**1st Approach: USE Scanf**

```
var in string
fmt.Scanf("%q", &in)
```

But then your input should be enclosed within the double quotes like `"2 3"`

**2nd Approach: USE bufio**

The best way I consider

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
for scanner.Scan(){
   in = scanner.Text()
   break  //optional line if your input has a single line
}
fmt.Println(in)
```

This shall solve the problem in the best way

Answer (score 1):

It is because `fmt.Scanln` doesn't take inputs after first space so if you entered 2 3 4 at `fmt.Scanln(&in)` then only 2 will be assigned to in.

Try using package `bufio`:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
scanner.Scan()
in := scanner.Text()
wh = strings.Split(in, " ")
fmt.Println(wh[0])
fmt.Println(wh[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Scanln seemed to only read until a space so I solved this problem by using an extra string

```
fmt.Scanln(&in, &in1)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647039/how-to-use-fmt-scanln-read-from-a-string-separated-by-spaces

Comment: @Dean But this won't solve the problem if you have unknown number of inputs. Added to that, declaring more variables is a bad practice .  Better to use bufio scanner

Comment: The two inputs are the width and height of a 2d object so number of inputs will always be two. However your suggestion is better in the cases you outlined so I set it as the best answer. :)