# It only returns the first word when reading input

Tags: go

I want to return the input, but, when I try to return the whole input it only returns the first word. I don't know what's wrong.

```
package main

import ("fmt")

func main() {
    var long_name string
    fmt.Print("----\nLong name here <> ")
    fmt.Scanln(&long_name)
    fmt.Print(long_name)
    fmt.Scanln()
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647039/how-to-use-fmt-scanln-read-from-a-string-separated-by-spaces

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use fmt.scanln read from a string separated by spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647039/how-to-use-fmt-scanln-read-from-a-string-separated-by-spaces)

Answer (score 1):

I recreated your scenario based on the suggestions from comments

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var long_name string
    fmt.Print("----\nLong name here <> ")
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    for scanner.Scan() {

        long_name = scanner.Text()
        fmt.Println("Long name:", long_name)

    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Long name here <> herold jame patison 
Long name: herold jame patison
```